# angularjs bootstrap datepicker value not getting changed when selecting second time

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I'm working on a **datepicker** for **angularjs** which is working as expected. But when I'm trying to select value second time from datepicker, the value is not getting changed. Following is the code snippet so far I've tried :-

***HTML***

```
<div id="dvFromDate" class='input-group date' datetimepicker ng-model="FromDate">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="FromDate" class="form-control" @*tooltips tooltip-template="dd/mm/yyyy"*@ required>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        $('#dvFromDate').datetimepicker({
                                            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                                        });
                                    });

                                </script>
```

***AngularJs***

```
    app.directive('datetimepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                element.find('input').val(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
            }    

            element.on('dp.change', function () {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            read();

            function read() {
                var value = element.find('input').val();
                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am also setting the datepicker value to empty string on a **selectionchanged** event of **select dropdown** like the following :-

```
$scope.FromDate = '';
$scope.ToDate = '';
```

After setting the dropdown value to empty string, whenever I select any value from datepicker, value is getting null. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: create fiddle  please

Comment: Please see the fiddle : - [Angular boostrap datepicker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o3UvmjFKqUhZWihh1f84?p=preview)

Comment: I want to see the changes on text inputs whenever I select a date from datepicker

Comment: You should look at how to convert a jquery plugin to a angular directive. Theres plenty of resources out there to help you understand better what you are trying to achieve. Mixing jquery and angular like you have is not the right way! Also look at how to access parent scope in directive

Comment: I can't set the previous value again If I set the value of datepicker to empty string. That's the main problem I'm facing, otherwise everything is working fine.

Comment: (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup) Currently I'm using this datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console in your plnkr, you'll see jquery isn't loading properly.......

See this plnkr. Its not perfect but will give you a start!

https://plnkr.co/edit/oyBF62NkNS3sMwumxk7F?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.FromDate1 = "5/5/2016";

});
app.directive('datetimepicker', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element(element).datepicker({
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          onClose: function(dateText, inst){
            $timeout(function(){scope.$parent.model.FromDate1 = dateText});
             console.log(scope.$parent.model.FromDate1);
             console.log(dateText);
          }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>AngularJs Date Picker</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>From Date</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1" datetimepicker />
      </div>
      <div>From Date<input type="text" ng-model="model.FromDate1"/></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Updated plunker : [Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o3UvmjFKqUhZWihh1f84?p=preview )                                                                                   1. Select a date, you can see the value on input box                                                                                            2. Click on reset button                                                                                 3. Again select the same date selected before                                        The issue is this time you cannot see the value. Following is the updated plunker

Comment: dp.change only fires when you change the date value, selecting the same date won't change the value stored in the picker. You should use dp.hide event instead.

Answer (score 0):

On the bootstrap-datepicker.js file, I have commented out lines from the following method:

```
 notifyEvent = function (e) {
            //if (e.type === 'dp.change' && ((e.date && e.date.isSame(e.oldDate)) || (!e.date && !e.oldDate))) {
            //    return;
            //}               
            element.trigger(e);
        },
```

and now whenever I select the same date again, value binding just working fine. Please see the updated plunker :
[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o3UvmjFKqUhZWihh1f84?p=preview)